# Using elements of vector to intersect named list

Tags: r

I have the following vector of elements:

```
list_alg <- c("rf", "nnet", "knn", "rpart")
```

and I wish to intersect it with the following named list:

```
list_tune <- list(
  glmnet = caretModelSpec(method = "glmnet"),
  svm = caretModelSpec(method = "svmRadial"),
  rf = caretModelSpec(method = "rf", importance = TRUE),
  nnet = caretModelSpec(method = "nnet"),
  knn = caretModelSpec(method = "knn"),
  rpart = caretModelSpec(method = "rpart")
)
```

I've tried variations of `intersect(list_alg , list_tune)`; however this returns an empty list. My goal is to create list that includes elements of `list_alg` vector; however also keeps the other elements of `list_tune` (Please see example output below).

The output I am trying to achieve would look like this:

```
list(rf = list(method = "rf", importance = TRUE), nnet = list(
    method = "nnet"), knn = list(method = "knn"), rpart = list(
    method = "rpart"))

$`rf`
$`rf`$`method`
[1] "rf"

$`rf`$importance
[1] TRUE


$nnet
$nnet$`method`
[1] "nnet"


$knn
$knn$`method`
[1] "knn"


$rpart
$rpart$`method`
[1] "rpart"
```

Comment: Try `list_tune[names(list_tune) %in% list_alg]`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you. I wonder why I haven't thought of this.

Comment: Or: `list_tune[ list_alg ]`